# Is the fibrous material on the back of this wallboard asbestos?

Tags: plaster, asbestos

[image]

Hi all. Just smashed this through. Is it asbestos? House is UK built 1982.

Please help. I'm having huge anxiety about this.

Thank you

Comment: 1982 was 3 years before the ban on the blue & brown stuff, and 10 years before the ban on the whits stuff ([link](https://www.asbestos.com/mesothelioma/uk/)), so some anxiety is potentially justified. But it would probably be best alleviated by going to buy an asbestos test kit rather than relying on guesses over the internet

Comment: Tell us a little more. Is this an exterior wall? What type of insulation does the home have? Is this wall adjoining an attached garage?

Comment: It is the boiler room wall into the bedroom. Above a staircase if that makes any difference?

Comment: Boilers used to be wrapped in the stuff, I don't know about boiler rooms but I'd be cautious.  As long as you don't disturb it, there's no risk.  I would cover it if it's subject to drafts or other air movement.